# When opening "Close Vote" dialog, loading graphic is clickable and causes crash

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, android-app

When I cast a close vote in the Android app, it's possible for me to click on the loading graphic before the close reasons populate. This causes the application to hang for a second or two, then crash.

The error report indicated an `indexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

**Details**:

- Stack Exchange: *1.0.7*
- Android: *4.3*
- Phone: *HTC One*

Comment: This is still an issue in the 1.0.5 release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh, that's an awesome find. It's been fixed for the 1.0.8 release, thanks!

Comment: Alright; I'll accept the answer when 1.0.8 is available!

Comment: And verified! Thank you for the fix!

Comment: Kasra, just as a heads up, I was able to cause a crash when clicking a different loading graphic (the one that briefly appears when voting on a comment). However, since it is much harder to click on, I'd count it as being less of a priority.