# Close option given before I have the privilege

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, privileges, android-app

I currently have 1542 rep on Web Apps SE, so don't get an option to **Close**.

[image: Stack Exchange Web Close menu]

When using the Android App (thanks to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/206819/227233)) I do get the **Close** option, but since I don't have that privilege yet it just loads a spinning loading icon (similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213064/227233) but sans crash).

[image: Stack Exchange App Close menu]

Sure, I could just pretend like it isn't there, but I'm guessing I'm not meant to have the **Close** option in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212976/close-vote-box-infa-loads-on-android-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in version 1.0.2 which is being pushed to devices as we speak, thanks!